# No wireless section in network connections 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I have [this motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5552#ov). The problem is that no wireless section is available in my network connections panel.

Could anyone help me to install the appropriate Intel wireless card drivers?

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #19 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:00dd Microsoft Corp. Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Already included. Isn't it working? If so please edit your question and describe your problem instead of asking for a non-solution.

Comment: the problem is described in the title...i cannot see wireless section in network connections..

Comment: Which has nothing to do with Ubuntu or drivers. The WiFi is probably disabled in BIOS/UEFI, the default setting. Please check.

Comment: Could you give us the stdout from `sudo ìwconfig`?

Comment: lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: no output @Pilot6

Comment: OK. Then post output of `lspci` and `lsusb`.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have edit my answer

Comment: There is no wireless device there.

Comment: i know there is no wireless device...i am trying to figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a newer Intel wireless device after looking at the motherboard spec.  In terminal run
`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge` 
That should install the 4.8 kernel and then run the following two commands to install firmware

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

Reboot

Comment: unfortunately that did not work..

Comment: @tsiro Have you checked in UEFI/BIOS yet, like I suggested? Again, the default is disabled. You need to explicitly enabled it there.

Comment: i have checked..but there is an option for enabling wireless network